# MS Access: Adding a verification field to records that have been emailed?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have email functionality built into my MS Access database that queries all records added based on a timestamp that equals today's date and adds them to a report which is emailed. This is not automated, as not every day has record entered into it, but user triggered - usually at the end of the day.

But what if someone forgets?

The query could be rewritten to filter the timestamp for `>=Date()-1` (or however many days), but we really don't want to send the same record more than once. Is there a way that, when the query runs to send the email, it marks the records that are sent so they aren't sent again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a select query cannot update.

But somehow you must be able to modify your code generating the mails to update the table records one by one marking each the record with a timestamp.

Then, when mailing, filter out records with a timestamp.

Comment: or create a secondary table that tracks records that are sent.  Cross check against this table every time your run the email code, and update as you send emails.